# Find coordinates using circle radius to create shapes

Tags: javascript, coordinates, kineticjs, geometry, shapes

I'm using a script to create shapes, usually you can use an image map to plot coordinates but this script is using coordinates from a circle radius.

Is there a tool to plot coordinates from circle radius or an better way to plot coordinates for example:

This is for a polygon/star shape and its very difficult to get the shape symmetrical.
I will be making other shapes that will be more complex

```
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 70, height / 2 - 120, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 0, height / 2 - 250, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 70, height / 2 - 120, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 220, height / 2 - 120, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 120, height / 2 - 0, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 180, height / 2 + 180, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 0, height / 2 + 120, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 180, height / 2 + 180, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 120, height / 2 - 0, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 220, height / 2 - 120, circleRadius));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using a background image the same shape as you require, that will help you to get the shape exactly as you require.

For a polygon as you said try using these coordinates which should give you a better shape.

```
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 60, height / 2 - 60, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 0, height / 2 - 250, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 60, height / 2 - 60, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 260, height / 2 - 60, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 100, height / 2 + 60, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 + 160, height / 2 + 250, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 0, height / 2 + 130, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 160, height / 2 + 250, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 100, height / 2 + 60, circleRadius));
circles.push(new Circle(width / 2 - 260, height / 2 - 60, circleRadius));
```